# Jackson deserializer of a List property of any generic type

Tags: java, jackson

I have classes like

```
public class ClassA{
    private String id;
    private List<ClassB> bClass;
}

public class ClassB{
    private int id;
}

public class ClassC{
    private String id;
    private List<ClassD> dClass;
}

public class ClassD{
    private String name;
}
```

I am reading a json from a source which I can deserialize into a `ClassA` or `ClassC` object. I am planning to write a custom deserializer for this task like this:

```
public class StringToObjectDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<List<B>> {
    public StringToObjectDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public StringToObjectDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public List<B> deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode jsonObject = p.getCodec().readTree(p);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.readValue(jsonObject.textValue(), new TypeReference<List<B>>() {
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see that I am typing the return object of the deserializer as `List<B>`. What I would like is to have a single deserializer which would return `List<B>` or `List<D>` depending on the object property that is getting deserialized into. This is because both the deserializers have the same logic, only difference being the typing. I know that type erasure happens at runtime but is there any way around this?

I have tried `public class StringToObjectDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<List>` as the signature, but it only returns a hash map which fails to map to the list of objects.

I want to use the deserializer by registering a `SimpleModule` like:

```
SimpleModule deSerializerModule = new SimpleModule();
        deSerializerModule.addDeserializer(<what to put here?>, new StringToObjectDeserializer());
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .registerModule(deSerializerModule);
        List<A> listA = mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(readJson), new TypeReference<List<A>>() {});
```

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:**

The reason I require a custom deserializer is due to the need of parsing 2 different types of json inputs:

Type 1:

```
{
    "id":"abc123",
    "bClass":[{
        "id":123
    },{
        "id":456
    }]
}
```

Type 2:

```
{
    "id":"abc123",
    "bClass":"[{\"id\":123},{\"id\":456}]"
}
```

Type 1 can be parsed easily by Jackson itself and I am indeed doing so in a place but handling Type 2 is the challenge as it is a string representation of a json array.

Currently I have a hack in place which manually converts the input from Type 2 to Type 1 before putting it through the mapper but I don't find it elegant.

Comment: What is stopping you from doing this with Jackson out-of-the-box? Why would you need to map the same source JSON to two different java classes? Can you include an example of JSON source and which are the two mapping cases?

Comment: I have added the example use cases